# How to include count of products including subcategories in WooCommerce menu?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following code for a dropdown menu in WooCommerce (in my theme functions.php) and I would like to display the total count of products in each category, but also include the subcategories' total products.

```
    // Check if the item is a Category or Custom Taxonomy
    if( $item->type == 'taxonomy' ) {
        $object = get_term($item->object_id, $item->object);

        // Check count, if more than 0 display count
        if($object->count > 0) {
            $output_new = '';
            $output_split = str_split($output, strpos($output, '</a>') );
            $output_new .= $output_split[0] . "<span class='menu-item-count'>".$object->count."</span>" . $output_split[1];
            $output = $output_new;
        }
    }    

    return $output;
}
```

The output is like this:

```
<li id="menu-item-1595" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children"><a href="https://example.com/category"><img width="150" height="150" src="https://example.com/example-150x150.png"><span>Top Level Category</span><span class="menu-item-count">4</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4031" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://example.com/product-category/product-subcategory/">SubCategory</a><span class="menu-item-count">74</span></a></li></ul>
</li>
```

but I need it to render this:

```
<li id="menu-item-1595" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children"><a href="https://example.com/category"><img width="150" height="150" src="https://example.com/example-150x150.png"><span>Top Level Category</span><span class="menu-item-count">78</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4031" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://example.com/product-category/product-subcategory/">SubCategory</a><span class="menu-item-count">74</span></a></li></ul>
</li>
```